# Google Play Store without payment

Tags: google-play-store

Can I use Play Store with no credit/debit card, or PayPal or code to redeem. I have no intent of paying anything, what I want is free, so I don't want to put cards online. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything. Google accounts without payment info work right after creation.

The only negative on a non-pay account is that in Google Play Store if you download an app from time to time you get a nag screen about "Completing your account set-up" where you can specify your payment data, but there is always an option to **Skip** this dialog without negative effect (see sample screen-shot below).

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't show a skip option

Comment: @StephaniePowers Have you noticed the big large `Skip` button on the left side on the bottom?